# Populate listview using simplecursor adapter

Tags: android, sqlite

I have been trying to populate a listview from a sqlite data base using a Simplecursor adapter. I get the following error

08-09 06:52:07.875  21262-21262/com.example.s210121629.myhealth E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.s210121629.myhealth, PID: 21262
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.s210121629.myhealth.contacts.FragmentContact.displayContacts(FragmentContact.java:85)
            at com.example.s210121629.myhealth.contacts.FragmentContact.onCreateView(FragmentContact.java:47)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1789)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:955)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1138)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:740)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1501)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:458)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)

The Contacts table does have a contact in it.

I have incuded my database helper class (**DBHelper**) below

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String TAG = "DBHelper";

    // Columns of Person Table
    public static final String TABLE_PERSON = "Person";
    public static final String COLUMN_PERSON_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_PERSON_USERNAME = "Username";
    public static final String COLUMN_PERSON_PASSWORD = "Password";
    public static final String COLUMN_PERSON_NAME = "Name";
    public static final String COLUMN_PERSON_SURNAME = "Surname";
    public static final String COLUMN_PERSON_GENDER = "Gender";
    public static final String COLUMN_PERSON_DOB = "Dob";
    public static final String COLUMN_PERSON_HEIGHT = "Height";
    public static final String COLUMN_PERSON_WEIGHT = "Weight";
    public static final String COLUMN_PERSON_SYSTOLICBP = "Systolicbp";
    public static final String COLUMN_PERSON_DIASTOLICBP = "Diastolicbp";
    public static final String COLUMN_PERSON_BPDATE = "Bpdate";
    public static final String COLUMN_PERSON_MAXRATE = "Maxhrrate";
    public static final String COLUMN_PERSON_MINRATE = "Minhrrate";

    // Columns of Medical Profile Table
    public static final String TABLE_MEDICAL_PROFILE = "MedicalProfile";
    public static final String COLUMN_MEDICAL_PROFILE_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_MEDICAL_PROFILE_USERNAME = COLUMN_PERSON_USERNAME;
    public static final String COLUMN_MEDICAL_PROFILE_DATE_DIAGNOSED = "DateDiagnosed";
    public static final String COLUMN_MEDICAL_PROFILE_CONDITION = "Condition";


    // Columns of Contact Table
    public static final String TABLE_CONTACT = "Contacts";
    public static final String COLUMN_CONTACT_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_CONTACT_USERNAME = COLUMN_PERSON_USERNAME;
    public static final String COLUMN_CONTACT_NAME = "Kinname";
    public static final String COLUMN_CONTACT_SURNAME = "Kinsurname";
    public static final String COLUMN_CONTACT_CELLPHONE = "Kincellphone";
    public static final String COLUMN_CONTACT_CAREGIVER_NAME = "Caregivername";
    public static final String COLUMN_CONTACT_CAREGIVER_SURNAME = "Caregiversurname";
    public static final String COLUMN_CONTACT_CAREGIVER_CELLPHONE = "Caregivercell";
    public static final String COLUMN_CONTACT_CAREGIVER_TELEPHONE = "Caregivertel";


    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "myHealth.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public SQLiteDatabase db;

    // SQL statement of the person table creation
    private static final String SQL_CREATE_TABLE_PERSON = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PERSON + "("
            + COLUMN_PERSON_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + COLUMN_PERSON_USERNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + COLUMN_PERSON_PASSWORD + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
            + COLUMN_PERSON_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
            + COLUMN_PERSON_SURNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
            + COLUMN_PERSON_GENDER + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
            + COLUMN_PERSON_DOB + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
            + COLUMN_PERSON_HEIGHT + " REAL NOT NULL,"
            + COLUMN_PERSON_WEIGHT + " REAL NOT NULL,"
            + COLUMN_PERSON_SYSTOLICBP + " INTEGER NOT NULL,"
            + COLUMN_PERSON_DIASTOLICBP + " INTEGER NOT NULL,"
            + COLUMN_PERSON_BPDATE + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
            + COLUMN_PERSON_MAXRATE + " INTEGER NOT NULL,"
            + COLUMN_PERSON_MINRATE + " INTEGER NOT NULL "
            + ");";
    // SQL statement of the medical table creation
    private static final String SQL_CREATE_TABLE_MEDICAL_PROFILE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_MEDICAL_PROFILE + "("
            + COLUMN_MEDICAL_PROFILE_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + COLUMN_MEDICAL_PROFILE_USERNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + COLUMN_MEDICAL_PROFILE_DATE_DIAGNOSED + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + COLUMN_MEDICAL_PROFILE_CONDITION + " TEXT NOT NULL "
            + ");";

    // SQL statement of the contact table creation
    private static final String SQL_CREATE_TABLE_CONTACT = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACT + "("
            + COLUMN_CONTACT_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + COLUMN_CONTACT_USERNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + COLUMN_CONTACT_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
            + COLUMN_CONTACT_SURNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
            + COLUMN_CONTACT_CELLPHONE + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
            + COLUMN_CONTACT_CAREGIVER_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
            + COLUMN_CONTACT_CAREGIVER_SURNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
            + COLUMN_CONTACT_CAREGIVER_CELLPHONE + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
            + COLUMN_CONTACT_CAREGIVER_TELEPHONE + " TEXT NOT NULL"
            + ");";

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_TABLE_PERSON);
        database.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_TABLE_MEDICAL_PROFILE);
        database.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_TABLE_CONTACT);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(TAG,
                "Upgrading the database from version " + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion);
        // clear all data

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_PERSON);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_MEDICAL_PROFILE);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACT);
        // recreate the tables
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public DBHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }


    /* The following Sql statements are used to manipulate the tables that have been created for the myHealth database */

    public void createPerson(String username, String password, String name, String surname, String gender, String dob, double height, double weight, int systolic, int diastolic, String bpdate, int maxhr, int minhr) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_PERSON_USERNAME, username);
        values.put(COLUMN_PERSON_PASSWORD, password);
        values.put(COLUMN_PERSON_NAME, name);
        values.put(COLUMN_PERSON_SURNAME, surname);
        values.put(COLUMN_PERSON_GENDER, gender);
        values.put(COLUMN_PERSON_DOB, dob);
        values.put(COLUMN_PERSON_HEIGHT, height);
        values.put(COLUMN_PERSON_WEIGHT, weight);
        values.put(COLUMN_PERSON_SYSTOLICBP, systolic);
        values.put(COLUMN_PERSON_DIASTOLICBP, diastolic);
        values.put(COLUMN_PERSON_BPDATE, bpdate);
        values.put(COLUMN_PERSON_MAXRATE, maxhr);
        values.put(COLUMN_PERSON_MINRATE, minhr);
        db.insert(TABLE_PERSON, null, values);
    }

    public void createMedicalProfile(String Username, String condition, String datediagnosed) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_MEDICAL_PROFILE_USERNAME, Username);
        values.put(COLUMN_MEDICAL_PROFILE_CONDITION, condition);
        values.put(COLUMN_MEDICAL_PROFILE_DATE_DIAGNOSED, datediagnosed);
        db.insert(TABLE_MEDICAL_PROFILE, null, values);
    }

    public void createContact(String Username, String name, String surname, String cell, String carename, String caresurname, String carecell, String caretel) {
        db = getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_CONTACT_USERNAME, Username);
        values.put(COLUMN_CONTACT_NAME, name);
        values.put(COLUMN_CONTACT_SURNAME, surname);
        values.put(COLUMN_CONTACT_CELLPHONE, cell);
        values.put(COLUMN_CONTACT_CAREGIVER_NAME, carename);
        values.put(COLUMN_CONTACT_CAREGIVER_SURNAME, caresurname);
        values.put(COLUMN_CONTACT_CAREGIVER_CELLPHONE, carecell);
        values.put(COLUMN_CONTACT_CAREGIVER_TELEPHONE, caretel);
        db.insert(TABLE_CONTACT, null, values);

    }

    public boolean checkContactTable() {
        db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = null;
        boolean tableexists = true;
        String selectQuery = " SELECT *  FROM " + TABLE_MEDICAL_PROFILE;

        Log.d("LOG", selectQuery);
        try {
            c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

            if (c.getCount() < 1) {
                c.close();
                tableexists = false;
            }
            c.moveToFirst();
            c.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, TABLE_CONTACT + "Does not exist");
        }
        return tableexists;
    }

    public String getPassword(String Username) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        String selectQuery = " SELECT " + COLUMN_PERSON_PASSWORD + " FROM " + TABLE_PERSON + " WHERE "
                + COLUMN_PERSON_USERNAME + " = '" + Username + "'";

        Log.d("LOG", selectQuery);

        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        if (c != null)
            c.moveToFirst();
        c.moveToFirst();
        String password = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Password"));
        c.close();
        return password;
    }

    public Person getPerson(String Username) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        String selectQuery = " SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_PERSON + " WHERE "
                + COLUMN_PERSON_USERNAME + " = '" + Username + "'";

        Log.d("LOG", selectQuery);

        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        if (c != null)
            c.moveToFirst();
        c.moveToFirst();
        Person person = new Person();
        person.setmHeight(c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex("Height")));
        person.setmWeight(c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex("Weight")));
        person.setmSystolic(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("Systolicbp")));
        person.setmDiastolic(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("Diastolicbp")));
        person.setmMaxrate(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("Maxhrrate")));
        person.setmMinrate(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("Minhrrate")));

        c.close();
        return person;
    }

    public boolean getMedicalProfile(String Username) {
        db = getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = null;
        boolean tableexists = true;

        String selectQuery = " SELECT " + COLUMN_MEDICAL_PROFILE_USERNAME + " FROM " + TABLE_MEDICAL_PROFILE + " WHERE "
                + COLUMN_MEDICAL_PROFILE_USERNAME + " = '" + Username + "'";

        Log.d("LOG", selectQuery);
        try {
            c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

            if (c.getCount() < 1) {
                c.close();
                tableexists = false;
            }
            c.moveToFirst();

            String username = c.getString(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("Username")));
            c.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, TABLE_MEDICAL_PROFILE + "Does not exist");
        }
        return tableexists;
    }


    public void updatePersonalInfo(String Username, Double height, Double weight, int systolic, int diastolic, int maxrate, int minrate) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues updatedvalues = new ContentValues();
        updatedvalues.put(COLUMN_PERSON_HEIGHT, height);
        updatedvalues.put(COLUMN_PERSON_WEIGHT, weight);
        updatedvalues.put(COLUMN_PERSON_SYSTOLICBP, systolic);
        updatedvalues.put(COLUMN_PERSON_DIASTOLICBP, diastolic);
        updatedvalues.put(COLUMN_PERSON_MAXRATE, maxrate);
        updatedvalues.put(COLUMN_PERSON_MINRATE, minrate);
        db.update(TABLE_PERSON, updatedvalues, COLUMN_PERSON_USERNAME + " = '" + Username + "'", null);

    }

    public void insertMedicalcondition(String Username, String condition, String dateadiagnosed) {
        db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_MEDICAL_PROFILE_USERNAME, Username);
        values.put(COLUMN_MEDICAL_PROFILE_CONDITION, condition);
        values.put(COLUMN_MEDICAL_PROFILE_DATE_DIAGNOSED, dateadiagnosed);
        db.insert(TABLE_MEDICAL_PROFILE, null, values);


    }

    public void insertContact(String Username, String name, String surname, String cell, String carename, String caresurname, String carecell, String caretel) {
        {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(COLUMN_CONTACT_USERNAME, Username);
            values.put(COLUMN_CONTACT_NAME, name);
            values.put(COLUMN_CONTACT_SURNAME, surname);
            values.put(COLUMN_CONTACT_CELLPHONE, cell);
            values.put(COLUMN_CONTACT_CAREGIVER_NAME, carename);
            values.put(COLUMN_CONTACT_CAREGIVER_SURNAME, caresurname);
            values.put(COLUMN_CONTACT_CAREGIVER_CELLPHONE, carecell);
            values.put(COLUMN_CONTACT_CAREGIVER_TELEPHONE, caretel);
            db.insert(TABLE_CONTACT, null, values);
        }
    }

    public Cursor readContacts() {
        db = getWritableDatabase();
        String[] allColumns = new String[]{COLUMN_CONTACT_ID, COLUMN_CONTACT_NAME,
                COLUMN_CONTACT_SURNAME,
                COLUMN_CONTACT_CELLPHONE,
                COLUMN_CONTACT_CAREGIVER_NAME,
                COLUMN_CONTACT_CAREGIVER_SURNAME,
                COLUMN_CONTACT_CAREGIVER_CELLPHONE,
                COLUMN_CONTACT_CAREGIVER_TELEPHONE,
        };
        Cursor c = db.query(TABLE_CONTACT, allColumns, null,
                null, null, null, null);
        if (c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
        }
        return c;
    }
}
```

The **FragmentContact** fragment

```
public class FragmentContact extends Fragment {

    @InjectView(R.id.contactslist)
    ListView _contactlist;
    private ContactDAO mContactDao;
    String kinname, kinsurname, kincell, caregivername, caregiversurname, caregivercell, caregivertel;
    private SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter;
    DBHelper mdbHelper;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contacts, container, false);
        ButterKnife.inject(getActivity(), view);
    //    this.mContactDao = new ContactDAO(getActivity());
        mdbHelper = new DBHelper(getActivity());


        displayContacts();

        return view;
    }

    public void displayContacts()
    {
        Cursor cursor = mdbHelper.readContacts();
        String[] columns = new String[]{
                mdbHelper.COLUMN_CONTACT_NAME,
                mdbHelper.COLUMN_CONTACT_SURNAME,
                mdbHelper.COLUMN_CONTACT_CELLPHONE,
                mdbHelper.COLUMN_CONTACT_CAREGIVER_NAME,
                mdbHelper.COLUMN_CONTACT_CAREGIVER_SURNAME,
                mdbHelper.COLUMN_CONTACT_CAREGIVER_CELLPHONE,
                mdbHelper.COLUMN_CONTACT_CAREGIVER_TELEPHONE};


        // the XML defined views which the data will be bound to
        int[] to = new int[]{
                R.id._inputname,
                R.id.inputsurname,
                R.id.inputcell,
                R.id.inputcaregiver_name,
                R.id.inputcaregiver_surname,
                R.id.inputcaregiver_cell,
                R.id.inputcaregiver_tel
        };
        // create the adapter using the cursor pointing to the desired data
        //as well as the layout information
        dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                getActivity(), R.layout.fragment_contacts,
                cursor,
                columns,
                to,
                0);

        _contactlist.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    }
}
```

I have included all the variables that are needed to populate the simplecursor adapter, and the application still crashes. I have included the code for the both the Database helper class and the fragment class where i implement the simplecursor adapter

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Your stack trace does not seem to line up with your code. Your stack trace shows a `NullPointerException` directly in `onCreateView()`, and I do not see any lines in `onCreateView()` that could directly raise a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 1):

According to the stack trace, you get a

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist

To avoid this, rename the column 'person_id' of your table 'Contacts' to '_id'.

In addition to that, in your 'readContacts()' method set

```
      String[] allColumns = new String[]{ COLUMN_CONTACT_NAME,
            COLUMN_CONTACT_SURNAME,
            COLUMN_CONTACT_CELLPHONE,
            COLUMN_CONTACT_CAREGIVER_NAME,
            COLUMN_CONTACT_CAREGIVER_SURNAME,
            COLUMN_CONTACT_CAREGIVER_CELLPHONE,
            COLUMN_CONTACT_CAREGIVER_TELEPHONE,
            COLUMN_CONTACT_ID
    };
```

to make the order of the database columns match with the order of the TextViews. The '_id' column is included for formal reasons but if you are not interested in its value you do not need to provide a corresponding TextView.

In general, if you want to use a kind of CursorAdapter, make sure your table contains a column named '_id' (like a primary key) and make that column part of the selected columns.

Lastly, you need to bind the ListView '_contactlist' to the corresponding ListView in the layout file in your 'onCreateView()':

```
View view = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contacts, container, false);
...
 // in the layout file 'fragment_contacts.xml'
 // let the ListView have an attribute 'android:id="@+id/theListViewId" '
_contactlist = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.theListViewId);
```

Comment: I have made the suggested changes and I now get the following error

Comment: @Tungamirai - which line is line 85 in FragmentContact?

Comment: @ 0X0nosugar   line 85 is    _contactlist.setAdapter(dataadapter);

Comment: @Tungamirai - I think this is because '_contactlist' is null (should be instantiated in 'onCreateView()' ). BTW better put the ID at the end of your selected columns or the values won't be shoved into the right TextViews (in 'readContacts()' )

Answer (score 0):

First problem was that my cursor was not returning all the columns in the the Contact table.
The second problem is that i had not instantiated the listview. the final code looks as follows :

```
public class FragmentContact extends Fragment {

    @InjectView(R.id.contactslist)
    ListView _contactlist;
    private ContactDAO mContactDao;

    private SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter;
    DBHelper mdbHelper;
    @InjectView(R.id._inputname)
    TextView _inputname;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contacts, container, false);
        ButterKnife.inject(getActivity(), view);
    //    this.mContactDao = new ContactDAO(getActivity());
        mdbHelper = new DBHelper(getActivity());
        _contactlist = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.contactslist);

        displayContacts();

        return view;
    }

    public void displayContacts()
    {
        Cursor cursor = mdbHelper.readContacts();
        String[] columns = new String[]{

                mdbHelper.COLUMN_CONTACT_NAME,
                mdbHelper.COLUMN_CONTACT_SURNAME,
                mdbHelper.COLUMN_CONTACT_CELLPHONE,
                mdbHelper.COLUMN_CONTACT_CAREGIVER_NAME,
                mdbHelper.COLUMN_CONTACT_CAREGIVER_SURNAME,
                mdbHelper.COLUMN_CONTACT_CAREGIVER_CELLPHONE,
                mdbHelper.COLUMN_CONTACT_CAREGIVER_TELEPHONE,
                mdbHelper.COLUMN_CONTACT_ID
                };



      //  Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" + cursor, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // the XML defined views which the data will be bound to
        int[] to = new int[]{
                R.id._inputname,
                R.id.inputsurname,
                R.id.inputcell,
                R.id.inputcaregiver_name,
                R.id.inputcaregiver_surname,
                R.id.inputcaregiver_cell,
                R.id.inputcaregiver_tel
        };
        // create the adapter using the cursor pointing to the desired data
        //as well as the layout information
        dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                getActivity(), R.layout.contacts_listitems,
                cursor,
                columns,
                to,
                0);

        _contactlist.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    }
}
```